# Laravel Event: how to fire and pass value to a listener after a controller method is called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In this case, we have 3 tables:

`tasks (task_id, task_title,task_type)`
`managers (manager_id, manager_title, manager_type)`
`assigners (task_id, manager_id)`

In `TaskController.php`, I have a store method to create new task

```
public function store() {  
    $input = Input::all();
    $this->task->create($input);
     return Redirect::route('tasks.index');}
```

Here's what I want to achieve:

1. Pass the newly created task value to an event `task.created`,
2. Compare the new task title `$task->task_title` with any `$manager->manager_title`, if any matches found (`$task->task_title` LIKE `$manager->manager_title`), then pass the matched `$task->task_id` and `$manager->manager_id` as an array to another event,
3. In an event listener located in start/global, it will create new record(s) in assigners table with values received from step2.The event listener is written as below:

   ```
   Event::listen('task.created',function($param1,$param2){  
       $new_assigner = new Assigner;  
       $assigner->task_id = $param1;  
       $assigner->manager_id = $param2;  
       $new_assigner->save();  
   });
   ```

My questions:

1. Where to fire the event in step 1 (in TaskController?) and what parameter should be used as a value to pass ($this->task?)
2. How to achieve step 2? (there maybe more than one matches found)

Answer (score 2):

1. Since you need newly created task, it should be after the task has been created. May be after this line. You can pass newly created task as it is or, pass the task_id and fetch it in  the event listener. But you have grab the task first.

   ```
   $task = $this->task->create($input);
   Event::fire('task.created', array($task) );
   ```
2. Using for each loop.

   ```
   Event::listen('task.created', function($task)
   {
       $managers = getManagersForThisTask($task);

       foreach($managers as $manager ){
           Event::fire('task.created_step2', $task, $manager );
       }
   });
   ```